# Laravel routing: the Kohana way (routes relative to controller)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, kohana

I am looking for a way to dynamically route my Laravel 5 application. This is what I want:

```
http://domain.ext/hello/world
```

The above url should automatically call the controller 'hello' with the method 'world()'.

Or another example:

```
http://domain.ext/pages/profile/settings
```

This URL should rout to the controller pages/profile with the method settings().

Of course, when parameters should be given, I will have to specify the route. But for the more simpler routes I would love to use the example above.

For the people that are familiar with the Kohana Routing style, that is exactly what I am looking for. I have found the following article, it gets me halfway there. Just wondering if I can get the method from the url too somehow.

http://tech.insideroy.com/?p=33

Comment: I believe the implicit controller method on the link you gave is the closest you can get.  Laravel routing just doesn't work that way.

Comment: and how about `post/put/delete` requests ? eg `POST http://domain.ext/hello/world` (should this one call `hello@world` too ?)

Comment: Good point, maybe something about hello@postWorld and hello@getWorld then? I'm not sure if it is posible to make it more efficient then as the link I shared above.